# python db connectivity with mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I am using sql workbench, php code in tools of workbench for db connection is:

```
$host="215.157.120.106";
$port=3386;
$socket="";
$user="root";
$password="";
$dbname="pay";

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
    or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

//$con->close();
```

I want the query in python.
My attempt:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="215.157.120.106",user="root",db="pay",port=3386,passwd="")
```

but it gives error:

```
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'16.95.57.211' (using password: NO)")
```

Comment: Is the password intentionally blank or you edited for this post?

Comment: as provided in php code generated by sql workbench, password is not required for connecting to this db.

Comment: Try doing it with a password and see if that fixes it (doubtful on that), or there seems to be a permission issue. Possibly run `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY "YOUR_ROOT_PASSWORD";` from your php code.